# replace all odd values in vector with coresponing value from new vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector, stdvector

Given following vectors:

```
std::vector<int> foo{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
std::vector<int> bar{10,20,30,40,50,60,70};
```

In the end I want `foo` to contain values `{ 10, 2, 30, 4, 50, 6, 70 }` meaning replacing all odd values.

I've tried the algorithm std::replace_if, but how to access the bars corresponding value?

```
// replace_copy_if example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::replace_copy_if
#include <vector>       // std::vector

bool IsOdd (int i) { return ((i%2)==1); }

int main () {
  std::vector<int> foo{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
  std::vector<int> bar{10,20,30,40,50,60,70};

  std::replace_if (foo.begin(), foo.end(), IsOdd, 0);

  std::cout << "foo contains:";
  for (auto i: foo){ std::cout << ' ' << i; }
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}

// output         : foo contains: 0 2 0 4 0 6 0
// desired output : foo contains: 10 2 30 4 50 6 70
```

Comment: What if both arrays differ in sizes?

Comment: good point. In my specific case it's checked beforehand, because data would be corrupt

Comment: So you want to replace the values in `foo` but you test print `bar`, what's up with that?

Comment: fixed that in code, that it matches the decription

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) overload that takes two input iterator ranges:

```
std::transform(foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(), foo.begin(),
  [](auto const& a, auto const& b) {
     if (a % 2)
        return b;
     return a; 
  }
);
```

Comment: A ternary would make the lambda's code shorter and, IMHo, clearer: return a%2 ? b : a

Comment: @UriRaz Yes, for the sake of brevity, I did consider the option of using the *ternary operator* instead (i.e., `return (a%2)? b: a;`, a single `return` statement) in the body of the lambda expression. However, I thought it could hinder readability.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the answers here you can make a function of your own:

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/yf3jYx

```
void IsOdd (const std::vector<int>& a, std::vector<int>& b) { 
    for(size_t i = 0; i < a.size() && i < b.size(); i++){
        if(b[i] % 2 == 1)
            b[i] = a[i];
    }
}
```

and call it in main:

```
IsOdd(bar, foo);
```

Comment: The question says - "In the end I want " foo " to contain values { 10, 2, 30, 4, 50, 6, 70 } meaning replacing all odd values." You replacing ' b ' with ' a ' means " bar " with " foo ".

Comment: @ManojBanik, so it does, the fact that the printed vector is bar threw me off.

Comment: @ManojBanik, I did it when you pointed out my error, just forgot to change the output text. Thanks for debugging my code, ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
// replace_copy_if example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <vector>       // std::vector

int main () {
  std::vector<int> foo{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
  std::vector<int> bar{10,20,30,40,50,60,70};

  for (size_t i = 0; i < bar.size(); i++)
  {
     if (foo[i]%2==1) foo[i]=bar[i];
  }


  std::cout << "bar contains:";
  for (auto i: foo){ std::cout << ' ' << i; }
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: anastaciu, How come this code replacing even numbers? Have you read the question? @aleem md, you can use "if (foo[i]%2)" instead of "if (foo[i]%2==1)". The code should check the length of both arrays at the beginning, otherwise it may cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

`std::replace_if` only supports replacing elements with the constant value specified as last argument. However, if you feel that it makes any sense for you, you can write your own `replace_if` function based on the [reference implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) and make it accept some kind of generator as a last parameter. For example:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class UnaryPredicate, class Generator>
void my_replace_if(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last,
                UnaryPredicate p, Generator g)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if(p(*first)) {
            *first = g();
        }
    }
}

bool IsOdd (int i) { return ((i%2)==1); }

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> foo{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    std::vector<int> bar{10,20,30,40,50,60,70};
    int i = 0;
    my_replace_if (foo.begin(), foo.end(), IsOdd, [&bar, &i]()
        {
            return bar[i++];
        });
    for (auto el : foo)
    {
        std::cout << el << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

===== EDIT =====

As pointed out by anastaciu, index for generator should be incremented with each step, not only when  generator is invoked.

e.g.:

```
    my_replace_if (foo.begin(), foo.end(),
        [&i](int v) { i++; return ((v%2)==1); },
        [&bar, &i]() { return bar[i-1]; });
```

But to be honest, it really is overkill in this case and it doesn't even look nice.

Comment: This outputs `10 2 20 4 30 6 40`

Comment: like that approach, would be an overkill for my specific case, since it is only used once

Answer (score 1):

You can make a use of [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```cpp
std::vector<int> result;

std::transform(
    foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(),
    std::back_inserter(result),
    [](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
        if (a % 2 == 0) {
            return a;
        }
        return b;
    }
);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxEAGZXpAA6oFhdbT1DE0FvXzU6Kxt7IycXd0VlTFV/BgJmYgJA41NOBJVw2lT0gki7R2c3DwU0jKzg3Ori0ujYyoBKRVQDYmQOAHIpV2tkQywAanFXHXVq4kxmI0nsMZWVgHo1ser0EBQugnEABgBBQeHRzAmptmASQgRF12XVja2CHZA5z2FegH00TwAT1%2BeCoR1OkiGtBGBnGkx0ADckkRiEtVujXttdkjVCRweDrAQxkZmNYxhA2hMAOyyE7orEgHEo%2BGEtE0VDiGm5SSkDy8ACspAAbKQqZyACKTWnHenvbHIvFTVlPMYOdKc6ScQ6kSTa1za7ja/naoXaqmHCVS8Gyj5MxXTehouYKAysA6uaXW1YMgjEEQKGjEIwQL3olbsgB0TmA1gppDGkfMcdV6SjmBjtDjobDDLVyAA1iDaEoMs4IM7XQQOtn0eJ%2BbJ%2BeKIGhi0TmAYiFIhWNmPGW9Uex2OZJuw42jXVhqJ2GxqDycwJpJ%2BWNJFdJa5xWNDpSp3SZ/uVnMCN1aD2rXuDytLRfL0eT6rzzL99enytxx6vdmGWgO1cdPDF0kdkxhbNJrAUEApEkR90UDech1nEAE1QVBxxpN4Ph/Il4QAsA%2BjGPC/wAvApWpSUb2/fYiKmAiBn5HRaDwx8vzlPZfxwmioLVYgQLoMDi0gyRoI/G84IgdsiEQlNiDQ6QMN2LDqJ0WiVI45SSI9MiWMwqi1NousGKYkTTgo1jFL0qCKzdXj6FJASoJg1YxIk1ApKsqsNXktjsKmXD8MIvSNLkl8bQU3TfJopj6MYgZjOzO9iFPC04qpcU%2Bg6VgQD6fk%2BlIUw%2BkOXLUCy/8ZDkLYuh6S5Bk4XKCCywq2g6fMQH5SQIyFVxzSpfkqU4AAOQ5OH5IVRqELLuFy/LCtIYq%2BlyiDtXqgr0tIOBYBgRA9iMTw8HYMgKGbVAdr2ipgAATh5Kg9oIZwIIgBwGtyhxrHSQEstq0g0CMIwtAIAB5WhWHelbSCwElRHYJ6wbwOZkiRCDQcwAAPJIO36GbCWUaHWDwBw/WIQE9CwD66uIPAjFJjoaHoJg2A4Hh%2BEEYRRBQOQ5CEPGIMgDpUE8ApEYAWm2SZxQkMqZEkZgFsSZINAgcw6hyUhzGacoXFyUI/DoJWQh8bXaDVmIKgaWWCiKWp9GyQQlHyFIahKawymNjXFAd3WGgdo3Wk4DoFEq3ouAyrKcry6G5uR/qhUFoVuDGYBkGQMZzojVcIFwQgSEXVxcjGPQTv27Pfbz9mZDqp6mtIFquojQVMr6SbSEp40w9BuaFpAJaK7WzaICQfZPA7chKG%2B3b9rMfAUUEGnGBYKHGYAdz9TwqfG7KpvDrKarGBf7jGSPo9j%2BPE%2BT1Py5WyuEHmLAXDjevG%2Bb7VpqKrKO67i/mpAbgqQjVwhUkS63BJD9U4Odfq3B3C8Hrq4DebdX6kGWo1YOfRJCwJmu3BBFcOhImIL4DQ3AgA%3D%3D)